# inserting blocks of text in haml

Tags: ruby, syntax, haml, markup, jekyll

In my Jekyll blog I use the include tag to put the contents of a file into the document. However if I attempt to do this with a HAML based document the indentation of the included text is wrong. `:preserve` does not work because it requires indentation. Is there a way to specify a block of text without depending on indentation?

```
%html
  %body
    - preserve do
<strong>included text from file</strong>
    - end
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems that in current version of Haml `:text` filter was removed. Now you can use `:plain` filter. No processing is performed for the text inside this block. You can paste multiline blocks of text or HTML code there. HTML will appear on the page unescaped.

```
:plain
  Some text <b>or HTML</b>.
```

Comment: Works with new lines as well

Answer (score 2):

For text, use filters:

```
:text
  some text
:erb
  <%= render :partial ... %>
```

http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#filters

Comment: I thought `render` was a rails thing not jekyll.

Comment: Yep, use the :erb filter for raw HTML as ERB extends HTML.

Comment: `:text` didn't work for me: `ActionView::Template::Error (Filter "text" is not defined.)`